# Error While Building Unity 5 Google Play Games for IOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I am currently using Unity 5.0.1f1 and google play games latest plugin.
I am exporting for ios with Scripting Backend as lL2CPP.
I have added all the frameworks and libraries as mentioned. Also added GoogleOpenSource.framework,GooglePlus.bundle,GooglePlus.framework,gpg.bundle,gpg.framework.

But whenever I tried to run using lL2CPP I am getting these error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_Quest_Copy", referenced from:
Quest_Quest_Copy_m532(Object_t, HandleRef_t103, MethodInfo) in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
(maybe you meant: _Quest_Quest_Copy_m532_MethodInfo, __Z21Quest_Quest_Copy_m532P8Object_t14HandleRef_t103P10MethodInfo )
"_QuestMilestone_Copy", referenced from:
QuestMilestone_QuestMilestone_Copy_m586(Object_t, HandleRef_t103, MethodInfo) in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
(maybe you meant: __Z39QuestMilestone_QuestMilestone_Copy_m586P8Object_t14HandleRef_t103P10MethodInfo, _QuestMilestone_QuestMilestone_Copy_m586_MethodInfo )
"_Event_Copy", referenced from:
Event_Event_Copy_m368(Object_t, HandleRef_t103, MethodInfo) in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
(maybe you meant: _Event_Event_Copy_m368_MethodInfo, __Z21Event_Event_Copy_m368P8Object_t14HandleRef_t103P10MethodInfo )
"_EventManager_FetchAllResponse_GetData", referenced from:
EventManager_EventManager_FetchAllResponse_GetData_m383(Object_t, HandleRef_t103, IntPtrU5BU5D_t137, UIntPtr_t104, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
 (maybe you meant:       __Z55EventManager_EventManager_FetchAllResponse_GetData_m383P8Object_t14HandleRef_t103P17IntPtrU5BU5D_t13712UIntPtr_t104P10MethodInfo,      _EventManager_EventManager_FetchAllResponse_GetData_m383_MethodInfo )
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But when I try Scripting Backend as Mono(2.x) it complies perfectly and works like a charm.
Can you please tell me Whats wrong with lL2CPP as I cant use Mono as IOS is not accepting build with Mono(2.x)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the symbols that are missing, You are most likely using an old version of the Google Play Games SDK.  Quests and Events were added in version 1.4.1 I suggest downloading the latest SDK from https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/sdks and retry building.

The other thing to check when you are updating the project is that the -ObjC flag is added in Other Linker flags.